# Insert Additional Text into HTML Page based on Dropdown List Value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was hoping to get some advice on the following. I have a dropdown box which has 15 separate options, when an option is selected a paragraph of text is displayed under it. Therefore I have 15 paragraphs of text each assigned as a 'Value' to the dropdown option.

The value is displayed under the dropdown box when an option is selected.

From an SEO perspective, I have been advised that this *may* be bad practice as Google may percieve this as 'hidden' text and give a low weight to the page when it comes to ranking.

How can I instead keep the text on a seperate page and 'pull' the additional value based on the dropdown list value?

The code I am working off is here:
https://codepen.io/mgsolid2010/pen/amrxRA

**HTML**

```
<label for="car">Car</label>
<select id="car">  
  <option value="---Select Option---">---Select Option---</option>
  <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
  <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<label for="engine">Engine</label>
<select id="engine">
  <option value="---Select Option---">---Select Option---</option>
  <option value="1.4 Petrol 1.4">1.4 Petrol1</option>
  <option value="1.6 Petrol">1.6 Petrol</option>
  <option value="2.0 TDI">2.0 TDI</option>
</select>

<button id="process">Update</button>



<a id="displayText" style="display: none"><p>Please select an option from the dropdown list above.</p></a>
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none"><h1><p>You have chosen a <span class="car">Ford </span> with a <span class="engine">1.4 Petrol</span> engine.</p></h1></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#process').on('click', function() {
  var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
  var car = $('#car :selected').text();
  var engine = $('#engine :selected').text();

  if (car == "---Select Option---" || engine == "---Select Option---" ){
  ele.style.display = "none";
  text.style.display = "block";
  } else{
  ele.style.display = "block";
  text.style.display = "none";
  $('p .car').text(car);
  $('p .engine').text(engine);
  }
});
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Are you getting append the result one by one depend on selected input value?

Comment: First, it might be best to try and validate that assumption before you assume it's true and requires a workaround (how does moving hidden content off the page help with SEO looking for that text?); you may wish to ask over on [webmasters.se].

Comment: I read the following thread, which made be think whether search engines may misinterpret my intentions:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521462/search-engine-indexing-of-single-page-applications/31535615#31535615

Comment: I remember working on this before. Posted a solution below which should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that should be a problem with SEO, it's a very normal thing to do. The only other way would be to have the text stored as a javascript string and insert it / remove it when needed. But i would not do this.

Comment: This may be a good work around, why would you not recommend this?

Comment: Well, depending on how your javascript is organized, it might not be good programming practice to have content on variables like that, instead on the view. I would not recommend because I think having them in the view and hiding is better and not that bad for SEO. But if you have a good structured Javascript code and something like a class/service/model that fetches text content, then yes, go with it.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to have the various paragraphs in the source code already, then just show/hide them as required.

Simple example ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fLz8xa8/1/)):

HTML

```
<select>
  <option selected>select...</option>
  <option data-for-para='1'>Option 1</option>
  <option data-for-para='2'>Option 2</option>
  <option data-for-para='3'>Option 3</option>
  <option data-for-para='4'>Option 4</option>
</select>

<div id='dropdown-paras'>
  <p id='para1'>Text for option 1</p>
  <p id='para2'>Text for option 2</p>
  <p id='para3'>Text for option 3</p>
  <p id='para4'>Text for option 4</p>
</div>
```

JS (jQuery)

```
var paras_cntr = $('#dropdown-paras');
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var para_id = $(this).children(':selected').data('for-para');
    if (!para_id) paras_cntr.children().hide();
    paras_cntr.children('#para'+para_id).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

CSS

```
  #dropdown-paras p { display: none; }
```

Comment: Thanks, though this currently the method I am using, and feel that as there is a paragraph of text assigned to each value, whether this will be considered 'hidden text'.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your code to simplify it a bit. This is perfectly SEO compliant, the text is in your markup.

Both drop downs need to have a valid option selected to show the sentence, or else it will remind the user to choose an option from both dropdowns.

```
    // HTML
    <label for="car">Car</label>
    <select id="car">  
      <option value="---Select Option---" class="first">---Select Option---</option>
      <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
      <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
    </select>

    <label for="engine">Engine</label>
    <select id="engine">
      <option value="---Select Option---" class="first">---Select Option---</option>
      <option value="1.4 Petrol 1.4">1.4 Petrol</option>
      <option value="1.6 Petrol">1.6 Petrol</option>
      <option value="2.0 TDI">2.0 TDI</option>
    </select>

    <button id="process">Update</button>

    <p id="defaultText">Please select the two options from the dropdown list above.</p>

    <p id="optionsText">You have chosen a <span class="car">Ford </span> with a <span class="engine">1.4 Petrol</span> engine.</p>

    // jQuery/JS
    $(function(){
        var ele = $('#defaultText');
        var opt = $('#optionsText');

        opt.hide();
        $('#process').on('click', function() {

        var carFirst = $('#car :selected').hasClass('first');
        var engineFirst = $('#engine :selected').hasClass('first');      

        if ( !carFirst && !engineFirst ){

          var carText = $('#car :selected').text();
          var engineText = $('#engine :selected').text();        

            ele.hide();
            opt.show();

            $('#optionsText .car').text(carText);
            $('#optionsText .engine').text(engineText);

        } else {
            ele.show();
            opt.hide();
        }
        });

    });
```

http://codepen.io/paulcredmond/pen/bwyrNG?editors=1011

Comment: Thanks for this! You see the text I would be displaying would be in paragraphs, would it still be SEO friendly if the following was the case: http://codepen.io/mgsolid2010/pen/ZpNjGz

Comment: Yeah, it would be. You're storing the options in the markup. All your JS is doing is displaying different combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of implementing this would be storing your paragraphs in javascript object, and use them as you select the dropdown options.

```
var data = [
   {car: 'ford', engine: ['petrol 1.4l', 'diesel 2l']},
   {car: 'suzuki', engine: ['petrol 1.4l', 'diesel 2l']},
   ...
]
```

Have a single element for description, and on `change` event of your dropdown, show the description from your javascript data.

Storing the data in object gives you better control and ability to keep your dropdown dynamic (unless rendering from server side), or use data in the app later.

Hope this helps